# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, qsort

I am using `qsort` function in c..its a in built function...it works well for strings having length less than 7..on strings whose length > 7, it gives "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

static int cmpr( const void *a, const void *b) { 
    return strcmp( *(char **)a, *(char **)b);
}


int main()
{
    int t;
    char str1[MAX],str2[MAX];

    scanf("%d",&t);

    while(t--)
    {
    scanf("%s %s",str1,str2);

    int len1=strlen(str1)/sizeof(char *);
    int len2=strlen(str2)/sizeof(char *);

    qsort(str1, len1, sizeof(char *), cmpr);
    qsort(str2, len2, sizeof(char *), cmpr);

    if((strstr(str1,str2)!=NULL)&& (strlen(str1)==strlen(str2)))
        printf("YES");
    else if((strstr(str2,str1)!=NULL) && (strlen(str1)==strlen(str2)))
        printf("YES");
    else if((strstr(str2,str1)!=NULL) && (strlen(str1)!=strlen(str2)))
        printf("NO");
    else if((strstr(str1,str2)!=NULL) && (strlen(str1)!=strlen(str2)))
        printf("NO");
    else
    printf("YES");
}



return 0;
}
```

...any idea why?

Comment: You should compile with all warnings and debugging info, and use the debugger. On Linux, compile with `gcc -Wall -g` (improve the code till no warnings are given) and debug with `gdb`. Your program is wrong, because `str1` should be an array of pointers....

Comment: Did you try using a debugger, to see which line gives a crash?

Comment: What are you attempting to sort here?

Comment: i m trying to sort characters of strings

Comment: qsort is inbuilt function in c

Comment: @GaganDeep If you want to sort just characters, see the last part of my answer, you need a different `cmpr` in addition to the changes Ed mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the lines

```
int len1=strlen(str1)/sizeof(char *);
int len2=strlen(str2)/sizeof(char *);
```

should read

```
int len1=strlen(str1);
int len2=strlen(str2);
```

Then the following should probably be changed

```
qsort(str1, len1, sizeof(char), cmpr);
qsort(str2, len2, sizeof(char), cmpr);
```

As we do not have code for `qsort` I would hazard a guess that the `cmpr` function is also incorrect.

Comment: i changed as per your guidelines, but still problem persists.

Comment: after changing cmpr ..it worked..thanks

Answer (score 1):

In

```
qsort(str1, len1, sizeof(char *), cmpr);
```

you sort an array of blocks of `sizeof(char*)` `char`s - which probably is not what you intended.

The address of such a block is passed to the comparison function,

```
static int 
cmpr(const void *a, const void *b) { 
  return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);
}
```

where it is interpreted as a pointer to a `char*` and then dereferenced. Then the block of `sizeof(char*)` `char`s in the array is passed to `strcmp`, where it is interpreted as a pointer to a 0-terminated character array. It very probably isn't.

The comparison function looks as if you want to sort the suffixes of the string. If that is the case, you need an array of pointers into the array `str1` to sort.

If you just want to sort the `char`s in the arrays, you should, as Ed Heal said, use

```
qsort(str1, strlen(str1), 1, cmpr);
```

(similar for `str2`), but you need to change your `cmpr` function to

```
static int cmpr(const void* a, const void* b) {
    return *(char*)a - *(char*)b;
}
```

then to compare the characters at the respective locations.

Comment: it worked after i changed cmpr ..thanks!